# Add a date column in pandas df using constant value in str

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

i have a table in pandas df

```
    product_id_x    product_id_y    count
0   2727846            7872456       1
1   29234              2932348       2
2   29346              9137500       1
3   29453              91365738      1
4   2933666            91323494      1
```

i want to add a new column 'dates' which i have defined in a str.

```
dateSelect = "'2016-11-06'"
```

so i added a new constant column

```
df['dates'] = dateSelect
```

but i am getting result as

```
   product_id_x   product_id_y    count   dates
0   2727846          7872456         1  '2016-11-06'
1   29234            2932348         2  '2016-11-06'
2   29346            9137500         1  '2016-11-06'
3   29453            91365738        1  '2016-11-06'
4   2933666          91323494        1  '2016-11-06'
```

the values in the dates are coming in quotes. and

```
type(df['dates']) = str
```

but i want it in date format, because further i am going to store this table in my mysql database. and i want the type to be date.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://name:pwd@xxx.xx.xx.x/dbname', echo=False)
df.to_sql(name='tablename', con=engine, if_exists = 'append', index=False)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can use first `replace` `'` by empty space and then [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
dateSelect = pd.to_datetime("'2016-11-06'".replace("'",""))
print (dateSelect)
2016-11-06 00:00:00

print (type(dateSelect))
<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

---

```
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime("'2016-11-06'".replace("'",""))

print (df)
   product_id_x  product_id_y  count      dates
0       2727846       7872456      1 2016-11-06
1         29234       2932348      2 2016-11-06
2         29346       9137500      1 2016-11-06
3         29453      91365738      1 2016-11-06
4       2933666      91323494      1 2016-11-06

print (df.dtypes)
product_id_x             int64
product_id_y             int64
count                    int64
dates           datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: yes sir, just seconds before your answer i too tried it, and it's working fine without .replace("'","")

Comment: Yes, if have double `""` and `''` together, first need remove inner quotes and then it works perfect. Or use only one like `"2016-11-06"` or `'2016-11-06'`, then `replace` is not necessary.

Answer (score 11):

most direct route

```
df['dates'] = pd.Timestamp('2016-11-06')
df

   product_id_x  product_id_y  count      dates
0       2727846       7872456      1 2016-11-06
1         29234       2932348      2 2016-11-06
2         29346       9137500      1 2016-11-06
3         29453      91365738      1 2016-11-06
4       2933666      91323494      1 2016-11-06
```

Answer (score 3):

Ahh! @jezrael got there first...

```
 print timeit.timeit("""
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import timeit
df = pd.read_csv('date_time_pandas.csv')
dateSelect_str = "2016-11-06"

# using standard datetime
dateSelect = dt.datetime.strptime(dateSelect_str,"%Y-%m-%d")
df['dates'] = dateSelect
#print(df['dates'])
""",number=100)


# Alternate method using pandas datetime
print timeit.timeit("""
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import timeit
df = pd.read_csv('date_time_pandas.csv')
dateSelect_str = "2016-11-06"

dateSelect = pd.to_datetime(dateSelect_str, format='%Y-%m-%d', errors='ignore')
df['dates'] = dateSelect
#print df['dates']
""",number=100)
```

gives output -

```
0.228258825751
0.167258402887
```

on an average.

**Conclusion** Using pd_datetime in this case is more efficient

Answer (score 0):

In it don't put double quote avoiding to define it as string.

```
dateSelect = '2016-11-06'  
df['dates'] = dateSelect
```

Answer (score 0):

For date range pd.date_range function is the best one..

```
dataFrame["Date Column"] = pd.date_range("1/08/2020", periods=len(dataFrame))
```

All the best!